# Find count of each character(case insensitive) in all the strings and print a report that shows count of each characters in descending order

Tags: javascript, string

INPUT
First line has an integer N
Next N lines has strings with size less than T number of characters
OUTPUT
Print count of each characters (case insensitive) present in all the strings. In each line, first display the character and then display the count. The characters should be displayed in descending order with the character that has the maximum count appearing on the top. If two characters have same count then display them in alphabetical order.

Constraints:
1 ≤ N ≤ 20,
1 ≤ T ≤ 10

EXAMPLE
INPUT:
2
yahoo
google

OUTPUT:
o 4
g 2
a 1
e 1
h 1
l 1
y 1

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Occurance {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc =new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the no of String :");
  int n=sc.nextInt();
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
         Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            String s=scn.next();  
    while(!s.equals(""))
    {
      char c=s.charAt(0);
      int count =s.length()-s.replace(c+"","").length();
      System.out.println(c+" "+count);
      s=s.replace(c+"","");
    } }    
}

}
```